# How can I convert a list of string to a list of integers?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```yaml
- debug: 
    var: my_list | select("greaterthan", 2) | list
  vars: 
    my_list: 
      - "1"
      - "2"
      - "3"
```

Errors: `'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

I've tried `my_list | int | select("greaterthan", 2) | list` but it does not give the expected result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert the items of the list to integers. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_list|map('int')|select('greaterthan', 2)|list }}"
      vars:
        my_list:
          - "1"
          - "2"
          - "3"
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": [
        3
    ]
```