# How can I convert a list into int in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

Unable to convert list into integer.

I have tried below code.

```yaml
- debug:
        msg: "{{ application_list }}
```

then we get below output..

```
ok: [ebppdoxs10] => {
    "msg": [
        "1674142504", 
        "1674138844"
    ]
}
```

after using filter int

```yaml
- debug:
        msg: "{{ application_list | int }}
```

then we get below output:

```
ok: [ebppdoxs10] => {
    "msg": "0"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible - How to convert list of string to list of integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62000030/6771046).

Answer (score 3):

[*map*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.map) the [*int*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.int) function to each item of the list. For example,

```yaml
  int_list: "{{ application_list|map('int')|list }}"
```

converts the strings to integers

```yaml
  int_list:
  - 1674142504
  - 1674138844
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    application_list:
      - "1674142504"
      - "1674138844"

    int_list: "{{ application_list|map('int')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: int_list
```